# Crispy form: render a field as HTML

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I've a form that contains various fields, some of them should be read-only, but instead of using a "read-only" field i would like to rednder them as HTML.

For examples i want:

`<p>{{form.text.value}}</p>` to be used. so that it's rendered as pure html and not as an input.

there's the `HTML` tag that works as a template, but I can't figure out how (and if) i can use it.

Assuming that my field is called `text`, what should I use to render it?

`HTML("This is the text {{text}}")` this does not work :(

Or should I create a new template for a new Field in oreder to render it as I want?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't use `crispy form` before but I try to help you. In a regular form, You can use `disabled=True` in your related form field. It automatically adds read-only feature to the template and an additional validation to avoid from changing the field.

According to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#disabled):

> The disabled boolean argument, when set to True, disables a form field using the disabled HTML attribute so that it won’t be editable by users. Even if a user tampers with the field’s value submitted to the server, it will be ignored in favor of the value from the form’s initial data.

So it will be much safer for your form.

An example:

```
class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    readonly_field = forms.CharField(disabled = True)
```

Then in your HTML template:

```
<form method = "POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
</form>
```

I guess you can handle with adding extra `crispy-form` template tags.

Comment: Thanks but this is different. I want to render the text as text in the HTML not as an Input without the edit possibility

Comment: This is what `disabled=True` also does. Users can see the data field but could not edit it. So it has read-only feature. If this is what you want could you clarify your point by editing the question?

Comment: I wanted to render them as pure `HTML`, like placing them in a `<p>`

Comment: Could you check this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually)?

Comment: You can make changes with `{{ form.name_of_field }}`.

Comment: will that render the "text" (value) of the field or rendere a field (<input>)?

Comment: Could you look at the [link](https://overiq.com/django-1-11/django-rendering-form-fields-manually/)? It will give you the necessary background.